# WPF Treeview: Skip a Level

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

Currently my treeview looks like this.

```
|Department
|-Program
|--Curriculum
|---Bloc
```

I wanted to skip the Curriculum part and make my treeview look like this.

```
|Department
|-Program
|--Bloc
```

This is currently my treeview in xaml. How can i change this? Do i need to change my models?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList}">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramList}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CurriculumList}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding BlocList}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearImplemented}"/>
                                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change model classes. You can use converter which change `ItemsSource` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Converter code:

```
public class CurriculumItemsSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{   
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Curriculum> curriculumList = value as ObservableCollection<Curriculum>;
        return curriculumList.SelectMany(c => c.BlocList);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`TreeView` code:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramList}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CurriculumList, Converter={StaticResource curriculumItemsSourceConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

where `curriculumItemsSourceConverter` is converter:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CurriculumItemsSourceConverter x:Key="curriculumItemsSourceConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
```

Comment: Awwww... Due to the long wait, I changed my my models even my database.. But let me try your answer.. I've also read that using converters is the way to go but I still haven't gotten my way around converters.. Thanks!!